# Regexp to find text in span tags, contained in another tag

Tags: html, regex, text, tags

I can't find a regex that will match the span number in span tag, can you help me plz ? im new in regex

> ```
> <br/>
> <span class="counter_key">Total number of messages: </span>
> <span class="counter_value">
>   14097 (
>   <a href="http://google.com">
>       more details
>   </a>)
> </span><br/>
> ```

Comment: **span number** , in your ex. would be **14097** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
<span class="counter_value">\s*(\d+)
```

Pattern description:

```
\s*             match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\d+             match a digit [0-9] between one and unlimited times
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vZ4nI2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your language supports `\k` then you could try the below regex to match only the number which was present inside  `<span>` tag,

```
<span class=\"counter_value\">\s*\K\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vZ4nI2/2)

Comment: I'm assuming they're using JavaScript, which doesn't support `\K`.

Comment: If so, i'll delete mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, assuming you're using javascript and there's guaranteed to only be one number in any given span of class `.counter_value`:

```
var num = $('.counter_value').text().match(/(\d+)/)[1];
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9KL/)